# How to run background service in phonegap even will close

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, rss, phonegap-pushplugin

I searched lot but still i am getting right ways to do this problem. I want to generate notification using Phonegap even app stop. I am getting data from rss feed . Whenever any one updating their feed and if i am using their feed, then i will get corresponding notification this content added in feed. please refer some sample or step or tutorial to do this. I am using android plate form to generate phonegap app.